# Camel prevents graceful Spring Boot actuator shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

Introducing version 3.20.1 of

- camel-spring-boot-starter
- camel-core
- camel-file-starter
- camel-endpointdsl

and

```
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true
camel.springboot.use-mdc-logging=true
```

to the application.properties and a simple file route to a Spring boot 2.7.8 web app using spring-boot-starter-actuator prevents the shutdown actuator from completing a graceful shutdown. Routes are shut down along with other Spring Components, but the VM does not exit as it does without Camel present.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that

```
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true
```

was what created the problem and it does not seem to be necessary anymore to keep camel running.